# DataTable Select Expression

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to select those gesellschaft_id's who have duplicates.  I used the code below. this is selecting distinct gesellschaft_id. How to write the select expression to select that row, which rows, gesellschaft_id have more values in the datatable?

```
foreach (DataRow dr1 in table1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow[] drDup = table2.Select("('" + dr1[0].ToString() + "' = gesellschaft_id ) AND Count(gesellschaft_id)>1");

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the `DataRow`s which have a `gesellschaft_id` which exists in more than one row:

```
var rowsWithADuplicateGesellschaftId = table1.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(row => row["gesellschaft_id"])
    .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public ArrayList FindDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string colName)
{
   Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
   ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();

   //add duplicate item value in arraylist.
   foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
   {
      if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
         duplicateList.Add(drow);
      else
         hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty); 
   }

      return duplicateList;
}
```

Also useful duplicate find and add/remove links:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4535-Remove-duplicate-records-from-table.aspx

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/94-remove-duplicate-rows-value-from-datatable.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, assuming that the first column is the one which you want to check for duplicates. This of course assumes that you have Linq available.

```
var duplicateIds = table2.AsEnumerable()
                         .GroupBy(row = row[0])
                         .Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

If you add a bit more detail to the question, that would be helpful.